# Unable to resolve module `SnapshotViewIOS'. Module does not exist in the module map

Tags: facebook, react-native

Please find exception for attached image.

I tried

> 1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
> 2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n
> 3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.

But nothing seems to fix below issue. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

[image: Unable To solve Module 'SnapshotViewIOS']

Full log here :

> "Unable to resolve module `SnapshotViewIOS` from
>   `/Users/dseerapu/Desktop/RDeal/DigitalMemberCard-FHNW/app/DigitalMemberCard/node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js`:
>   Module does not exist in the module map\n\nThis might be related to
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try
>   the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman
>   watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf
>   node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr
>   $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`."

Answer (score 0):

Terminate the process in the terminal and then run `npm start -- --reset-cache`